# Update angular scope on events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-digest

I am wrapping a web service client into an angular service. This particular client works emmiting events for particular updates like so:

```
app.service('AngularClient', function () {
  this.info = null
  this.login = function () {
    client.login(loginInfo).then(function (loggedClient) {
      loggedClient.on('newInfo', function (info) {
        this.info = info
      })
    })
  }
})
```

A controller uses this service and binds it to its `$scope`:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function (AngularClient, $scope) {
   $scope.client = AngularClient
})
```

However, anytime the `'newInfo'` event gets fired angular doesn't automatically trigger a `digest` cycle, so I can't control when the `info` gets updated in the UI. What's the angular way of making sure this happens everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep receiving updates to the login event, you could do something like this:

```
app.service('AngularClient', function () {
  this.info = null
  this.loginCallback = null
  this.login = function () {
    client.login(loginInfo).then(function (loggedClient) {
      loggedClient.on('newInfo', function (info) {
        this.info = info
        if (this.loginCallback) this.loginCallback(info);
      })
    })
  }
})

app.controller('Ctrl', function (AngularClient, $scope) {
   $scope.client = AngularClient
   AngularClient.loginCallback = function(info, err){ // optional error
     $scope.user.property = info.property;
     $scope.$apply();
   }
})
```

Comment: `$scope` is not in use by his service `AngularClient`. apply() should be used somewhere else.

Comment: $scope is not being used by his service, it is being used by a closure inside the controller.

Comment: Can a promise be resolved multiple times? The 'newInfo' event fires continously as long as there are updates on the service.

Answer (score 0):

Angular will not be aware that it should digest again if on custom async methods created by your code.

A way to get around that is to use `$scope.$apply()`. However $scope is not exposed to your service. So on your angular controller, you can wrap the listened function of your event into an `$apply()`;

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
    //your code here.    
});
```

http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html